# Is there free android emulator for ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: android, emulation

is it best to run on Windows via virtual box? i really couldn't find anything.

Comment: yes i did, 

first i tried bluestacks with ubuntu which wine don't support
second genymotion is not free and crashed twice.

any more ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is Genymotion(this is free if you create an account). This runs an Android instance inside virtualbox, but you need virtualbox installed for this to work, which can be installed using `sudo apt install virtualbox`. Then download the Genymotion deb and install it using `dpkg -i <path to file>.deb`.

You could also try Android-x86 and install in a virtual session of VMWare/VirtualBox. However most android apps won't run in it. You can find the isos here - www.android-x86.org

Also, you could try AVD in android studio. For this follow Google Developer instructions - https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator.html